# How to use column variables as column names

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I currently have the following query that goes:

```
SELECT a.instance_type, SUM(a.quantity) as quantity, b.name, b.id
FROM sales_iteminstance a
INNER JOIN inventory_item b ON b.id = a.fk_item_id
GROUP BY (a.instance_type, b.id)
ORDER BY (b.id)
```

Which returns:

```
+---------------+----------+----------+----+
| instance_type | quantity |   name   | id |
+---------------+----------+----------+----+
| Sell          |        5 | Gas 50Kg |  5 |
| Buy           |        8 | Gas 50Kg |  5 |
| Return        |        4 | Gas 50Kg |  5 |
+---------------+----------+----------+----+
```

Would it be possible to update the query to instead condense the table above and use `instance_type` as the column name? I.e.

```
+----+----------+------+-----+--------+
| id |   name   | sell | buy | return |
+----+----------+------+-----+--------+
|  5 | Gas 50Kg |    5 |   8 |      4 |
+----+----------+------+-----+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a simple pivot query can do this:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN instance_type = 'Sell'   THEN quantity END) AS sell,
    MAX(CASE WHEN instance_type = 'Buy'    THEN quantity END) AS buy,
    MAX(CASE WHEN instance_type = 'Return' THEN quantity END) AS "return"
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    id, name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `FILTER` clause in Postgres (9.4+)

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    MAX(quantity) FILTER ( WHERE instance_type = 'Sell' ) AS sell,
    MAX(quantity) FILTER ( WHERE instance_type = 'Buy'  ) AS buy,
    MAX(quantity) FILTER ( WHERE instance_type = 'Return') AS "return"
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    id, name;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a53d5/1)